# How to put vertical bar at the end of filled area of unity3d horizontal slider

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I am using unity3d horizontal slider to show a character's life like below
[image]

But I want to show a vertical bar at the end of filled area like in below image
[image]

Any idea? how to achieve this.

Comment: Can't you just add an image to the Slider object? Then make it the needed shape and you done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Lerping the localPosition of your vertical bar.

This would look something like the following:

```cs
GameObject verticalBar; //the gameobject you want to use
GameObject player; //Assume this is your play that has the health property
Vector3 startPos; //start position of your total healthbar
Vector3 endPos; //end position of your total healthbar

private void UpdateVerticalBarPosition()
{
    float normalized = player.currentHealth / player. maxHealth //this normalizes your current health to be between 0 and 1 
    if(!float IsNaN(normalized))//(optional) makes sure the value is valid.
    {
        verticalBar.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, normalized);
    }
}
```

This method will normalize your current HP. meaning that if for example your player has 70 health left of a total 100 health, the normalized value will be `0.7f`, or 70% of its total health.

Using this normalized value in a `Vector3.Lerp` that is clamped between `startPos` and `endPos` (here `startPos` would be the starting position of your total healthbar, so the left side of your grey bar. And `endPos` the ending positon of your total health bar, so the right side of your grey bar) will put the vertical bar 70% along of the way of your health bar. Which should be the same point where your yellow/orange bar stops.

If you call this method once when hp has changed it will jump to the new value. But if you take damage gradually you can also run it in a loop to make it slide across smoothly.

Alternatively. If you use Unity's `Slider` component for your healthbar you can also just use the `Slider.handleRect`. found in the documentations [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-handleRect.html) which would look something like this

```cs
Slider healthBar; //the slider used for your healthbar
GameObject verticalBar; // the bar you want displayed at the end of the healthbar

Start()
{
    healthBar.handleRect = verticalBar;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I found a simple one, have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, It was pretty simple though!
I just a added the vertical bar texture as child of fill image inside slider and I kept it right aligned.

cheers!